# Can You have More than One Homunculus Simultaneously Through Different Methods?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, summoning

The spell, [Create Homunculus](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spell:create-homunculus), specifies the following:

> You can have only one homunculus at a time. If you cast this spell while your homunculus lives, the spell fails.

However, the Homunculus Servant infusion of the Artificer lists no such restriction. Does that mean they can exist concurrently? Or is the spell more specific than the infusion, and so creates the case of specific trumping general? The spell seems to refer to itself when talking about homunculi(?), which is what begged the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, this works

The Artificer infusion creates a **Homunculus Servant**, while the spell creates a **[Homunculus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16926-homunculus)**. These are different creatures, with different stat blocks. You can have both at the same time.

Comment: That said, for the sanity of the DM and efficiency at the table, it's probably best to limit each player to at most one or two pets/summons/companions at a time. It's not hard for a player to acquire so many companion NPCs that it starts making them the star of the show just because that one player sucks up so much table time each round.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym, Yes - even for the sanity of the player themselves. My wizard had a veritable zoo of minions (Shield Guardian, animated dead, familiar, summoned mephits) and I stopped useing everything but the Shield Guardian and Familiar except for special situations, because it is just too much hassle when using a virtual table top (or minuatures, for that matter), to constantly drag everything around -- especially when, at higher levels, the impact of the weaker ones in combat starts to decline quite a bit.